# ボタンによる画像の遷移についてお伺いしたいです。

Tags: swift, uikit

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var alienImage: UIImageView!
    @IBAction func updateImage(sender: AnyObject) {

        alienImage.image = UIImage(named: "frame2.png")

    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

現状ストーリーボードには、frame1と言う画像が入っております。
ボタンを押すことで、frame2と言う画像に変化させたいのですが、変化が起こりません。

何が問題になっているのでしょうか？

Comment: outletの接続は正しくされているでしょうか？また、画像はどのように管理されていますか？アセットカタログで管理されているのであれば、`.png`が不要ということがあります。

Comment: .storyboardのxml、もしくはソースコード全体を提供いただけると、回答がつきやすいかと思いますよ。

Comment: ありがとうございます。

もう一度改変して質問してみようと思います。